# Need windows session saved when switching OS HD between PC's

Tags: windows, ssd, external-hard-drive, hibernate, session-restore

Recently I had an idea to increase my productivity so I could work with the same data and applications both on my business address and my home address.

The idea:
The idea was to use 1 SSD Hard Disk with Windows 10 installed that I would switch between pc's.

The problem:
I am a big fan of the hibernate option in windows because the session state is saved completely and you starts where you left of. The above scenario is working perfectly but only when I shut down the PC. When I put the PC in hibernate and switch from PC then on windows startup it diagnoses and fixes itself (this only takes a few seconds). But apparently when windows fixes itself it deletes the saved session state. No question that this is because of the hardware change.

Possible solutions:
The best solution would be if there is an application that saved the session even when I shutdown the pc instead of hibernate. After some searching I realize that such applications do not exist (Zinstall Twinsplay came close but not quite). 
Some suggest using a Virtual Machine which has the option to save session (= suspend). But I find using a VM impractical (especially when the "guest" would be my main workspace).

Are there any solutions for my problem (options in windows, software, …)?

Comment: Once you get round the problem of trying to boot to dissimilar hardware, how do you plan to tackle the problem of having to re-activate your Windows installation each time? Frankly, the workable solution to your issue is DropBox, iCloud, OneNote… etc

Comment: Why do you want to move the SSD between PCs? Also keep in mind that internal SATA connectors are only required to be rated to, I think, 50 insertion cycles (though I can't seem to find a citation for this right now). By doing this, you will be going through those very quickly: after doing this switch once per day for two months, the connectors are no longer required to be reliable.

Comment: There is no easy solution to this problem.  You are running into hard limits of both how Windows saves the session and more then likely doing what you describe also breaks the EULA for Windows.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Is that a fairly hard limit, on the SATA connectors on motherboards & the drives themselves too, not just the cables? That's seriously low. If you find the source for that I'd be interested to read it. OP - definitely just use a dropbox-like data file sharing solution, all that's really important is the data anyway, not a whole os or carrying around your drive every day.

Answer (score 1):

This just would not be possible due to different hardware configurations.

Using a VM is probably your only option in this situation

Answer (score 1):

As Harvey mentions, doing what you'd like is impossible using Hibernate as long as you don't have identical hardware at both sites. Even then, it's not assured to work.

Using a Virtual Machine seems to be your best shot, and might actually work fairly well. Should you decide to go this road, depending on the virtualization software you would use, you may want to Remote Desktop into your Virtual Machine for the best experience.

Keep in mind network connections will be disconnected and will need to be re-established (will they be available in the new location), which may incur some funky behaviour from applications upon resuming. Particularly, what I've had happen to me is VPN software (which I didn't disconnect properly) staying stuck in a reconnecting state after resuming, crippling all network connectivity until forcibly closed off.

Another solution, network allowing, might be to simply Remote Desktop in to either workstation over the internet and not suspending at all.